# Calling Convention in direct show filter

Tags: c++, com, directshow

I get the following exception when i call my filters getpin() method:

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved
>   across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a
>   function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer
>   declared with a different calling convention.

So it seems there is a wrong calling convetion used

I tried to fix this in the filter header:

Changed:

```
CBasePin*  GetPin(int n);
```

To:

```
CBasePin* __stdcall GetPin(int n);
```

But this won't compile because it says (translated from german)

> The overriding virtual function only differs from CBaseFilter::GetPin by calling convention

I also tried to set the calling convention in the project configuration but this didn't work.

So what do I do now?

This is the filter interface:

```
class MyFilter : public  CBaseFilter, public IMyFilter
{
public:

    DECLARE_IUNKNOWN;


    MyFilter(LPUNKNOWN pUnk, HRESULT* phr);
    virtual ~MyFilter(void);

    int  GetPinCount();
    CBasePin* GetPin(int n);


    void acceptFilterInput(LPCWSTR pinname, IMediaSample* sample);

    static CUnknown* WINAPI CreateInstance(LPUNKNOWN pUnk, HRESULT *phr);
    STDMETHODIMP NonDelegatingQueryInterface(REFIID riid, void ** ppv);

    STDMETHODIMP STDMETHODCALLTYPE  StartRecording();
    STDMETHODIMP STDMETHODCALLTYPE Pause();
    STDMETHODIMP STDMETHODCALLTYPE Stop();

    CCritSec m_lock_filter;

    CBaseInputPin* pin0;
    CBaseInputPin* pin1;
    CBaseInputPin* pin2;

    MCMyOutputPin *outpin;
private:

    CCritSec m_critSec;

    std::vector<IMediaSample*> samplesPin0;
    std::vector<IMediaSample*> samplesPin1;
    std::vector<IMediaSample*> samplesPin2;

    LPCWSTR currentInputPin;


    void workerThread();

    void processQueue(std::vector<IMediaSample*> pPinSamples);


};
```

THis is how I use the filter:

```
int static doSomeWork()
{

    CoInitialize(NULL);
    IGraphBuilder* pGraph = NULL;
    IMediaControl* pMediaControl = NULL;
    IMediaEvent* pMediaEvent = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IFilterGraph, (void **) &pGraph);

    if(hr < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    IBaseFilter* pSource = NULL;
    pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **) pMediaControl);
    pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEvent, (void **) pMediaEvent);
    pGraph->AddSourceFilter(TEXT("C:\\TEMP\\video1.avi"), 0, &pSource);

    IPin* pSourceOut = GetPin(pSource, PINDIR_OUTPUT);
    IBaseFilter* pAVISplitter = NULL;
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AviSplitter, NULL,   
                             CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                             IID_IBaseFilter,
              (void**)&pAVISplitter);

    IPin* pAvIIn = GetPin(pAVISplitter, PINDIR_INPUT);

    pGraph->AddFilter(pAVISplitter, L"Splitter");
    pGraph->Connect(pSourceOut, pAvIIn);

    IPin* pAVIOut = GetPin(pAVISplitter, PINDIR_OUTPUT);


    MyFilter* myfilter;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MyFilter, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)& myfilter);
    if(hr < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    IPin* myfilterIn = myfilter->GetPin(0);
    IPin* myFilterOut = myfilter->GetPin(3);
    pGraph->Connect(pAVIOut, myfilterIn);

    pGraph->Render(myFilterOut);

    CoUninitialize();


    return 0;
}
```

The error hapens at "myFilter->GetPin(0)"

Comment: Create a static method that does the same thing. I believe member functions pretty much have to be `__thiscall`.

Comment: I can't make it a static method because I have to have access to member variables

Comment: also it's an overriden method, can't be static

Comment: Is there anyway you could reproduce the problem in a small snippet of code?

Comment: @jliv902: the snippet provided is pretty small taking into account it's DirectShow code

Comment: instead of `MyFilter* myfilter`, try to use a IBaseFilter pointer and use queryinterface for the `IMyFilter` interface.

Comment: @AndyT The snippet wasn't there when I wrote that request! My COM knowledge is limited, but the code seems okay. The only thing I can think of is that some kind of buffer overflow is occurring or you are writing off by 1 somewhere.

Comment: @Wimmel Unfortunately this produces the same error

Comment: Is the registered filter in sync with the source code?

Comment: yes, I recompiled and registered it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are having is caused by your violating COM fundamentals.

```
MyFilter* myfilter;
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MyFilter, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
    IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)& myfilter);
```

`CoCreateInstance` or `QueryInterface` or similar with `IID_IBaseFilter` argument will return you `IBaseFilter*` pointer. You are supposed to correctly reinterpret received pointer for correct further use.

You take `IBaseFilter*` and then apply reinterpret cast to `MyFilter*` - this is not going to work. You still have `IBaseFilter*` pointer and calling other methods on it is causing undefined behavior.

To cut long story short, you cannot (you can, but beginner level version of the answer here is you cannot) have `MyFilter*` pointer on the controlling application, you can only have COM interface pointers there.